# Variadic function passing long but reading as va_arg(argList, int)

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit, variadic-functions

I'm in the process of converting a 32 bit application to 64 bit, one of the pain points I'm running to is variadic functions that expect a long but are potentially passed an integer e.g. argument is hardcoded as -1 instead of -1L stemming from the 64 bit change of long size to 64 bits. Take this example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

long varargsExample(int input, ...);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    varargsExample(5,
    "TestInt", 0,
    /* This will fail if read as a long */
    "TestIntNegative", -1,
    "TestLong", 0L,
    "TestLongNegative", -1L,
    NULL); 
}

long varargsExample(int firstArg, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char * name;
    long nextValue;

    va_start(args, firstArg);
    while ((name = va_arg(args, char *)) != 0)
    {
        /* If the type is changed to read in an int instead of long this works */
        nextValue = va_arg(args, long);

        printf("Got [%s] with value [%ld]\n", name, nextValue);

    }
    va_end(args);
    return 0;

}
```

Running this when compiled with GCC 64 bit results in:

```
Got [TestInt] with value [0]
Got [TestIntNegative] with value [4294967295]
Got [TestLong] with value [0]
Got [TestLongNegative] with value [-1]
```

Which makes sense because I'm guessing this is getting interpreted as:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

So padding an additional 32 bits to represent the long and we get 2^32 - 1 instead of a negative number. What I'm wondering however is if I change the va_arg read to read the value as an int this appears to work regardless of whether an int or long is passed e.g.:

```
nextValue = va_arg(args, int);
```

Is this a hack that just happens to work or is there something in the C specification that makes it so this will work consistently? Note that this application runs on both Unix/Linux and Windows there on Windows long is 32 bits so I'm not worried about the function being passed a value that can't be represented by a 32 bit integer. I created a basic unit test that goes through INT_MIN --> INT_MAX passing to a variadic function a mix of integers/longs and reading as va_arg(args, int) and it appears to work (tested on AIX, Solaris, and RHEL), but I'm not sure if this is just undefined behavior that happens to work on these platforms.

The correct fix here is to identify all the callers of this function and make sure they're passing a long in all cases but the use of these functions is fairly widespread/hard to identify without compiler support for identifying this. I'm trying to see as an alternative if there's a GCC extension I can take advantage of to specify custom variadic type checking similar to what is done for format argument checking (sprintf, printf etc.).

Comment: The only problematic point is x86_64: when you push a 32-bit value onto the stack, the upper half of the 64-bit stack element might very well be random garbage, so you mustn't use va_arg (ap, long) to fetch it.

The other direction (push long and pop int) is safe.

Comment: That's the "fix" I'm using right now, to read in as an int which appears to work regardless of a long or int being passed however as mentioned in the answers I'm guessing I'm relying on undefined behavior there. Any reason you're saying it's safe though outside of that?

Comment: Officially only these are supposed to always work when you pass them to a function: char->int, short->int, float->double.

Non-officially you might expect that a longer integer type converts well into a shorter one (but only if the longer fits into one stack-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler does [not know](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16p1) which types the variadic function fetches from the list, so it as to rely on the types of arguments given. It performs the [default argument promotions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p7) on the arguments.

For integer types, thes basically promote "smaller" types to `int` or `unsigned`, and pass `int`/`unsigned` and "larger" types unchanged.

When fetching argument, it is [your responsibility](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.1p2) to fetch the **correct** type from the variadic arguments. Anything else invokes *undefined behaviour*.

So, as you do not pass a `long`, but an `int` you have to fetch an `int`. The fault will likely get unnoticed (as you suspected) if both types have the same representation.

However, the other way 'round should also not work: taking a smaller `int` if a larger `long` has been pushed. However, for typical implementations, this will only be noticed when fetching the next argument. Either way, as this is all *undefined behaviour*, it is **vital** to avoid.

gcc has some support using function `__attribute__`s for `printf`/`scanf`-like format strings, but as the caller of your functions give no hint to the caller about the types, you are lost with respect to compiler-support (how should it know?).

Functions like the one you present are a common source of rioting programs and should best be avoided, because they are prone to typographic errors exactly like to one you have noticed now. It would be better to pass an array of struct to a proper function or call a fixed-argument function. They are often a radioactive legacy from times programmer fought for every line of code, be it run-time or size.

One alternative might be C11 using a macro with `_Generic` calling fixed-size functions for the various argument types.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually used gcc's __attribute__ to pick up compile time checks for custom functions that were in place in delegate to vsprintf. I was looking for something similar for other variadic functions along these lines and found [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#type-safety-checking) which seems to be for type checking on variadic arguments where the type is based on a previous type's value. I'd agree changing the function to achieve better type safety would probably be better but unfortunately this is a legacy API with a large amount of code behind it.

Comment: @RyanR: That seems to support some hard-coded formats only (mpi, fcntl, ..), but I might have overlooked something. Problem in general for such an attribute is it would require to execute compile-time code (e.g. a mini-language) to be universally useful for such; there are just too many possibilities how you can specify the argument types. Even more as you are using custom types and C determines type-identity for scalars by layout, not by name as other languages do. C is just not the language for introspection.

Comment: I played around with this a bit, you can use "argument_with_type_tag" on custom functions however it seems to be more a long the lines of doing things like:
if argument 1 is an int == 5 then make sure argument 2 is a char *
if argument 1 is an int == 6 then make sure argument 2 is a long

There's actually similar functions in the application I'm working on that do something like this where it could be useful (basically variadic functions that use a type enumeration that defines what the next argument should be, messy I know). But, it can't address the original use case I posted.

Comment: Going with this then that va_args(arg, int) is undefined behavior if a long is passed that just happens to work on most platforms I've tested against.

Comment: @rici: thanks for the edit, but I intentionally meant "rioting" (the others really were typos).

Comment: @RyanR: Yes, such code is the reason why C has such a bad reputation. Freedom means also you have to act responsible. A proverb often forgotten not only by programmers...

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C99, you can change the variadic function to a function which accepts a single argument supplied as a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html). Such literals can be arrays of unspecified length, so you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct NameAndLong {
    const char* name;
    long value;
} NameAndLong;

long varargsExample(NameAndLong things[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    varargsExample((NameAndLong[]){
      {"TestInt", 0},
      {"TestIntNegative", -1},
      {"TestLong", 0},
      {"TestSomethingBig",1L<<62},
      {"TestLongNegative", -1},
      {NULL}});
    return 0;
}

long varargsExample(NameAndLong things[])
{
    const char * name;
    long nextValue;
    while ((name = things->name) != 0)
    {
        nextValue = things++->value;
        printf("Got [%s] with value [%ld]\n", name, nextValue);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you'll have to replace all the function calls, but if you don't replace one, the compiler will tell you because there will be a clear prototype mismatch. And then you won't have to worry about people adding new calls and forgetting to add the `L`.

Personally, I find the extra pairing braces help with legibility, but the cast is a bit bulky. You might want to use a macro, but beware of the fact that macro arguments are separated by any comma not enclosed in *parentheses*. Braces don't count. You can get around that issue by using a variadic *macro*:

```
#define VA_EXAMPLE(...) (varargsExample((NameAndLong[]){__VA_ARGS__}))
// ...
VA_EXAMPLE({"TestInt", 0},
           {"TestIntNegative", -1},
           {"TestLong", 0},
           {NONE});
```

Here it is [live on ideone](http://ideone.com/bOXAsV) (with `long long` instead of `long`, to match the compilation environment.)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, unfortunately for the Windows side of things still using Visual Studio 2008 with this application (no C99 support til VS 2013 from my understanding). It would be nice to move to a type safe alternative but I'm trying to minimize the impact as this is a part of the application that is just in maintenance mode (no new features going in). I was hoping that GCC would have something I could hook into to generate compilation warnings similar to what's done for printf/sprintf but it doesn't look like there's an easy way to do this.